# Diferenças entre localStorage Vs sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Quais as diferenças, prós e contras entre `localStorage` e `sessionStorage`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ambos `localStorage` e `sessionStorage` se extendem de [`Storage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). Não há diferença entre eles, exceto para a **não-persistência** de `sessionStorage`.

A *não-persistência* como descrito acima é no sentido de que `sessionStorage` se faz disponível apenas para a janela que criou os dados até que tal janela seja fechada, ao abrir outra janela(*ou aba*) tais dados não estarão disponíveis.

Em contrapartida de `sessionStorage`, ao criar dados em `localStorage` esses dados estarão disponíveis para qualquer *aba/janela* mesmo que o usuário encerre a janela, reinicie o sistema, etc.

Um exemplo, vamos supor que você deseja salvar o nome de usuário e senha para realizar um login, é provável que você opte por armazenar esses dados em `sessionStorage` por motivos de segurança e salvar as configurações de usuário em `localStorage`.

---

Utilize `localStorage` para uso a longo prazo e `sessionStorage` quando você precisa armazenar algo temporário(ie *dados de uma sessão*).
Ambos também são escopo por fabricantes de navegadores. De modo que os dados de armazenamento salvos pelo *IE* não pode ser lidos pelo *Chrome* ou *FF*.

Você pode ver uma demonstração [**aqui**](http://www.theburningmonk.com/demos/web%20storage/storage_demo.html).

### Referências

<sub>1. [localStorage vs. sessionStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/local-storage-vs-session-storage)</sub>

<sub>2. [localStorage and sessionStorage](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/localstorage-and-sessionstorage)</sub>

Comment: Eu acho que fica ruim armazenar usuario e senha, como no seu exemplo, no session storage uma vez que dificilmente o usuario utilizará apenas uma aba ao utilizar seu sistema.

Answer (score 11):

[`sessionStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) - É semelhante a um [`cookie`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#refsCOOKIES) que expira ao fechar o navegador. ela possui a mesma extrutura do `localStorage`, porém não existe como mudar seu tempo de permanência, sempre que fechar irá ser excluída.

[`localStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) -  É semelhante a um [`cookie`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#refsCOOKIES), porém que nunca expira, desta forma enquanto houve os registros no `AppCache` referente à aquele domínio, a variável irá existir (A menos que o usuário crie uma rotina para remove-la).

Ambos os atributos foram acrescentados pelo [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). Os itens acima chamados de armazenamento na web.
Mas existem outras formas de armazenamento local através do `HTML5`, tal como base de dados [`WebSQL`](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/features/storage), Base de dados Indexadas [`(IndexDB)`](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/features/storage), assim como arquivos convencionais [`(File Access)`](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/features/storage).

Answer (score 6):

Separei alguns pontos que podem ser comparados entre localStorage, sessionStorage e cookies, tendo em vista que também podem ser utilizados para armazenamento.

#### Inicialização

[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) podem ser definidos tanto do lado do cliente quanto no lado do servidor utilizando o header `Set-Cookie` enquanto para o [LocalStorage](https://tutorial.techaltum.com/local-and-session-storage.html) e o [SessionStorage](https://tutorial.techaltum.com/local-and-session-storage.html) apenas são definidos no lado do cliente.

#### Tempo de expiração

Os cookies tem o tempo de expiração configurado manualmente, enquanto o localStorage não possui tempo de expiração e o sessionStorage expira ao sair da aba em que foi populado.

#### Escopo

Em relação ao escopo dos valores, com os cookies e o localstorage os valores são globais, já com os valores sessionStorage apenas podem ser acessados na aba em que foram definidos.

#### Capacidade de armazenamento

Por fim, a capacidade de armazenamento dos cookies são de 4kb enquanto no sessionStorage e no localStorage possuem uma capacidade muito maior com 5MB em ambos.

#### Referências

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

https://tutorial.techaltum.com/local-and-session-storage.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key