# Limpar cache de navegadores com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cache

É possível limpar o cache dos navegadores Firefox e Chrome via JavaScript? Com o Internet Explorer já consigo, mas não os citados acima.

Cara, não deu certo, creio que o problema ocorre porque salvo o usuario logado no remember-me ... mas, o problema ocorre só quando eu fecho o browser, se clico em sair funciona normalmente.

Você já viu algo parecido?

Se o usuário marcar o check box lembra eu adiciono um cookie:

```
if (model.RememberMe)
 {
     Response.Cookies["SistemaLeilao"].Value = model.UserName;
     Response.Cookies["SistemaLeilao"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
 }
```

Quando clica no sair e o `logoff` é feito, funciona filé, mas quando fecha a janela do browser sem fazer o `logoff` fica tudo gravado, e isso que ta me atrapalhando.

Comment: Eu só não estou surpreso que você consiga limpar o cache do IE via JS porque, afinal de contas, segurança nunca foi o ponto forte do IE.

Comment: window.onunload

Comment: A resposta é perfeita, fala a realidade, a pergunta e a afirmação estão completamente enganados.

Comment: Só quis ajudar a um amigo. A pergunta foi pra ele. Não é justificativa isso não, apenas me apoiei na dúvida dele que agora entendi que era minha também. Mas valeu a todos.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Não é possível, e se fosse seria uma enorme falha de segurança, pensou conseguir limpar o cache de qualquer pessoa que acessasse sua página?

O que você pode fazer é indicar para o navegador **não fazer cache da sua página**, isso pode ser feito utilizando uma dessas meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta ...

Comment: Cara, não deu certo, creio que o problema ocorre porque salvo o usuario logado no remember-me ... mas, o problema ocorre só quando eu fecho o browser, se clico em sair funciona normalmente.

Você já viu algo parecido?

Comment: Você está trabalhando com sessão? O que você quer fazer?

Comment: Se o usuário marcar o check box lembra eu adiciono um cookie:

 if (model.RememberMe)
 {
     Response.Cookies["SistemaLeilao"].Value = model.UserName;
     Response.Cookies["SistemaLeilao"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
 }
Quando clica no sair e o logoff é feito, funciona filé, mas quando fecha a janela do browser sem fazer o logoff fica tudo gravado, e isso que ta me atrapalhando.

Comment: @pnet Talvez seja melhor usar [SessionStorage](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage) em vez de um cookie então.

Answer (score 5):

Como dito [nesta resposta do Stack-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2181544/3153542), você pode usar:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

para forçar o navegador a recarregar os JS/CSS para a ***sua*** página apenas. Limpar o *cache* do navegador todo não é possível.

Answer (score 2):

Impedir o browser de utilizar o cache não me pareceu uma boa, pelo menos no meu cenário, então
procurando por uma solução para esta questão, vi muitas pessoas utilizando o formato a seguir:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meu.css?v=<?=filemtime($file);?>">
```

Porém no cenário que trabalho, cada vez que o sistema é atualizado no servidor, os arquivos que não foram alterados também são sobrescritos, alterando assim sua data de modificação, forçando o browser a fazer o download do asset mesmo que ele não tenha sido modificado, o que acho bem ineficiente, visto que o uso do cache fica prejudicado.

A solução que encontrei para fazer isso somente se o arquivo foi alterado, é  utilizar uma função de hash, o que só vai alterar o hash se o conteúdo do arquivo for de fato modificado.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meu.css?v=<?=hash_file('md5', $file);?>">
```

Estou utilizando tanto para arquivos .js quanto para .css, foi o que achei melhor, pois se o arquivo não foi alterado, é melhor deixar o cache trabalhar, caso contrário, o navegador irá fazer novamente o download do asset.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, o cache é um importante balanceador de carga e consumo de banda larga, não aconselho como membro do SOpt você utilizar a solução do @Laerte em todos os casos, cada caso deve ser estudado.

Imagine se sua página tivesse fotos de 500 Kb cada, e você quisesse exibir elas sempre em tamanho original, por exemplo, uma galeria de uma rede social. Sempre que o usuário logar na rede social e acessar a sua galeria, seria necessário o browser solicitar essa foto de 500 Kb ( bem como as demais ) já que você teria "feito o navegador não fazer cache da sua página". 
Se você tivesse deixado o cache armazenar essas imagens (localmente) seria muito mais rápido o carregamento do site e menor o consumo de banda.

Uma solução, quando você quer forçar algo ser constantemente atualizado e baixado (atualizado no cache), é criar um `src` de referências a `.CSS`, `.JS`, `imagens`, colocar uma variável via `GET` atualizada com um valor aleatório (`rand`). Essa também é uma solução do SOen como citou @user7261.

Apresentei uma solução semelhante aqui: [Tratar cache com AngularJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110288/tratar-cache-com-angularjs/114989#114989)

Comment: Também acho uma boa usar assim `?....`, mas não precisa de `rand()` o legal seria usar um versionamento.

Answer (score -2):

**Aplicações Estáticas ou com cache imutável segundo a especificação RFC8246:**

Acrescentar o código abaixo, no inicio da tag "`<head>`"

```
<meta name="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

Alternativamente, usar:

```
<meta name="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0,must-revalidate">
```

**Aplicações Dinamicas:**

As respostas são mentirosas, eu poderia usar um termo mais bonitinho "equivocado", mas sem motivo aparente, são incorretas, principalmente no tocante a "ser impossível" e ainda o parabenizam por uma gambiarra, sim, é gambiarra, pelo que vi no console, versionar não faz absolutamente nada, inclusive, não precisa versionar, basta recarregar a pagina duas vezes seguidas que o próprio navegador verá se existem alterações, eu não achei o que procurava por aqui, mas vou deixar um simples código que eu criei, com base na própria documentação oficial que mostra como se faz: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete.

**Passo 1:** Primeiramente, acesse o seu site, abra o console (F12), na parte superior, localize o menu: "Aplicativo", "Application" ou "Applications", clique sobre ele, agora, no menu lateral, localize "Cache", clique em "Armazenamento em cache" ou "Cache storage". (o que vier primeiro)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRvdX.png]

Anote o nome que você vê por lá, no meu caso: "devsite.pwa_RUNTIME_V3", se não aparecer nada, o seu problema é outro, deve ser com um proxy ou outro intermediador qualquer.

**Passo 2:** Agora crie um Cookie para todos os usuários que acessarem o seu site, use o nome de "version" e valor "2.0", nada de criptografar, deixe isso para depois, deve ser um cookie comum.

**Passo 3:** Recorte o seu script e coloque dentro do "else" abaixo, altere "devsite.pwa_RUNTINE_V3" para o nome que você anotou no **passo 1**, além disso, altere "/assets/css/style.css" para o caminho dos arquivos ou imagens que você deseja atualizar, incluindo o arquivo que você colocará esse código, salve o arquivo, limpe o cache do seu navegador e atualize a pagina.

```
console.info('script:', 'verificar versão...');
function verify(code){var cookiestring=RegExp(code+"=[^;]+").exec(document.cookie); return decodeURIComponent(!!cookiestring ? cookiestring.toString().replace(/^[^=]+./,"") : "");}

if(verify('version') !== '2.1'){
caches.open('devsite.pwa_RUNTINE_V3').then(function(cache) {
  cache.delete('/assets/css/style.css');
  cache.delete('/assets/js/script.js');
})
localStorage.clear();
console.info('script:', 'confirme a atualização.');
alert("Portuguese: Precisamos atualizar a página, esta é uma versão antiga.\n English: We need to update the page, you are on an old version.\n Español: Necesitamos actualizar la página, estás en una versión anterior.");
console.info('script:', 'recarregando...');
location.reload(true);
} else {
//cole o script aqui.
    }
```

Se tudo der certo e provavelmente dará, você verá um Alert, não clique em "ok", primeiro altere o valor do cookie que você criou no passo 2, para "2.1", agora sim você pode clicar em "ok", a pagina será recarregada automaticamente e seu cache será limpo.

De nada.

---

**Exemplo de como limpar o cache no Logout**

```
<button class="reset">Sair</button>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(".reset").click(function(){
    caches.open('devsite.pwa_RUNTINE_V3').then(function(cache) {
      cache.delete('/assets/css/style.css');
      cache.delete('/assets/js/script.js');
      cache.delete('/dashboard.html'); //nome e local correto do arquivo
    })
    localStorage.clear();
})
</script>
```

Comment: Poderia completar sua resposta mostrando qual é a relação entre a Web API Cache que utilizou na sua resposta com o cache interno do navegador, que é o foco da pergunta? Isso não ficou claro.

Comment: @Woss 10, não tem cache interno nenhum na forma que você se refere, a minha solução segue um caminho semelhante ao já apresentado pela Google em: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage#clear-storage, além disso, o problema dele pode ser resolvido com html: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control, não há nada de complexo aqui.

Comment: Então não entendi. Se o problema da pergunta pode ser resolvido com o cabeçalho Cache-Control, qual é a relação com a API Cache? No próprio MDN é citado que a API Cache não segue os padrões dos cabeçalhos de cache.

Comment: São duas formas de resolver a questão, ali, além da api de cache, limpa também a storage, além disso, é usado a "location.reload(true);", o que faz com que o navegador ignore o cache e carregue novos arquivos, tudo que ele informou é que não deseja o seu painel de controle em cache, você fez complementos que não estão na pergunta, o "cache interno do navegador".

Comment: Inclusive é uma duplicata desta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68382/for%C3%A7ar-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-arquivo-javascript-sem-desativar-cache, porem, perguntada de outra forma, a solução buscada é a mesma.

Comment: Mas assim, o SOpt por exemplo cacheia todas as páginas, então elas não deveriam aparecer na opção Aplicação > Cache > Armazenamento em cache do F12, como apontou? Aqui está vazio, mesmo que as páginas estejam cacheadas.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119681/discussion-between-macedo-montalvao-and-woss).