# Forçar atualização de arquivo JavaScript sem desativar cache

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iis

Em uma aplicação web de larga escala que desenvolvo ocorre um transtorno toda vez que acontecem atualizações, pois os navegadores, principalmente o Google Chrome, fazem *cache* de arquivos JavaScript e, certas vezes, ocorrem incompatibilidades entre o código do servidor e o do cliente, levando a situações e erros imprevistos.

Já consideramos versionar nossos arquivos JavaScript de forma que o nome deles carregue o número da versão, fazendo assim o navegador considerá-los novos arquivos, porém isso mostrou-se inviável devido à grande quantidade de arquivos que existem e à confusão que isso causa no nosso versionador (GIT).

Existe algum padrão ou solução que force o recarregamento do JavaScript toda vez que este for alterado, sem que o usuário tenha que dar um CTRL+F5 ou limpar o *cache*? Também não é uma opção desabilitar o *cache* das páginas.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no CACHE-CONTROL e EXPIRE do META?
http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html

Comment: Já vi o `Cache-Control`, mas pelo que eu sei só me permite desativar o cache, o que eu não quero. Já o `Expires` serve para robôs de busca retirá-los de seus resultados quando a data "expirar".

Comment: Entendi, sobre a versão no nome do arquivo do javascript você sabe que não precisa ser necessariamente no nome do arquivo né? Pode ser algo do tipo `seuarquivo.js?v=2`

Comment: Sim, já tinha visto essa solução, mas desisti dela pois li em algum lugar que os browsers estavam ignorando parâmetros de *query string* em arquivos `.js`. Alguém aí pode confirmar se essa solução ainda é viável e possível?

Comment: @MarcusVinicius pode ser que [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params) lhe de uma ideia. Nos usamos `query params` para limpar a *cache* e tem funcionado sem problemas ate agora.

Comment: Dá para gerar um `time()` e colocar na URL também.

Comment: Olá, Pelo que verifiquei geralmente é adicionada uma query string nas urls dos arquivos conforme link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936050/force-browser-to-reload-all-cache-after-site-update http://blog.toddbauer.me/2013/01/30/forcing-browsers-to-reload-css-js-files/ Essa técnica funciona pois mesmo o arquivo estando em cache caso seja enviado chamado com uma querystring diferente o browser interpreta como se fosse outro arquivo e realiza o reload.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Olá.

Existe uma técnica chamada de "Querystring Fantasma" que resolve esse problema na maior parte dos navegadores.

Em PHP é feito assim:

```
<link href="/file-css.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file-javascript.js?<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

Renderizado:

```
<link href="/file-css.css?1433981258" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file-javascript.js?1433981258"></script>
```

Isso gera uma URL diferente em cada "F5" e força o navegador baixar novamente o arquivo.

Essa técnica é usada para não ter que alterar as configurações de cabeçalho do servidor web.

## Atualização

A solução acima pode causar dois problemas:

1º) O aumento do tráfego de internet do servidor web.
2º) A aplicação web carrega mais lentamente porque não utiliza os benefícios do cache do navegador.

Então para resolver esses dois problemas existem duas soluções.

## 1ª solução:

Criar uma constante que seria atualizada apenas quando os arquivos CSS e JS mudarem de versão.

#### Em ASP.NET:

Coloquei no Web.config uma constante que indica a versão:

```xml
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Version" value="1254"/>
  </appSettings>
```

No Site.Master coloquei:

```html
<link href="/file-css.css?<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"] %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file-javascript.js?<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"] %>"></script>
```

#### Em PHP:

O recomendável é a constante "VERSION" ser criada em um arquivo do tipo "config.php". Mas coloquei ela aqui apenas para demonstração:

```php
<?php
define('VERSION', '1254');
?>
<link href="/file-css.css?<?php echo VERSION; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file-javascript.js?<?php echo VERSION; ?>"></script>
```

#### As duas linguagens de programação geram o mesmo resultado no HTML:

```
<link href="/file-css.css?1254" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file-javascript.js?1254"></script>
```

## 2ª solução

Escrever o HTML já propriamente dito alterando a numeração "1254" apenas quando os arquivos CSS e JS mudarem de versão.

Essa última solução considero a mais fácil.

Referências: [Prevent Your CSS and JavaScript Files From Being Cached](http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache)

Comment: Interessante, mas eu quero manter o cache, só quero atualizar o arquivo quando ele realmente mudar. Por isso acho que vou usar querystring com um valor constante, que mude somente quando eu alterar o conteúdo do arquivo.

Comment: O controle está na sua mão. Abraços.

Comment: Já faz tempo, mas vou dar como aceita a resposta por se aproximar mais da solução que encontrei.

Comment: Isso não é muito saudável. @MarcusVinicius está certo em não se dar por satisfeito. Baixar o mesmo arquivo, na mesma versão, a cada acesso é uma má prática.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre ASP.NET e não PHP.

Comment: A resposta foi atualizada.

Answer (score 3):

Como está utilizando ASP.NET, basta utilizar os recursos de *Bundling*. Ele irá gerenciar isso para você, criando uma URL diferente apenas quando houver uma nova versão do JavaScript, senão, ele irá orientar os browsers a recuperem do cache - http 306.

Quando cria-se um projeto ASP.NET com template no Visual Studio, na pasta `App_Start`, terá um arquivo chamado `BundleConfig.cs`.

Nele você configura os grupos de scripts ou estilos que serão publicados nas páginas.

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/jquery").Include(
                "~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/meus-scripts").Include(
                "~/scripts/meuscript1.js",
                "~/scripts/meuscript2.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/site").Include(
                "~/content/site.css"));

#if DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif

        }
    }
```

Em em suas *Views*, consome passando o nome dos agrupamentos:

```
<html>
<head>
@Styles.Render("~/content/site")
</head>
<body>
    <!-- conteudo -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/meus-scripts")
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Marcus Vinicius](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23593/marcusvinicius), pegando a idéia do Dadeke (Querystring Fantasma) e incrementando um pouco, cheguei a seguinte solução.
Adicionar um: `<?php echo filemtime("includes/script.js"); ?>`, desta forma quando atualizar o arquivo script.js, automaticamente mudará a 'querystring'.

Resultado final:

```
    <script src="script.js?"<?php echo filemtime("script.js"); ?>></script>
```

Comment: A pergunta é sobre ASP.NET e não PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Este exemplo precisa de uma junção entre: Banco de Dados + JQuery + Json + ASP Classic( substitua por sua linguagem de programação) + HTML

Crie uma tabela simples no banco de dados:

```
Tabela: atualize_me
Colunas: id( int, auto_increment ), status( bit, valor padrão: 1 )
Efetue um INSERT: insert into atualize_me(status) value(1)
```

coloque no arquivo( no meu caso arquivo.js )  principal que é executado em todas as página do site, as seguintes informações abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // SE TIVER ALGUMA ATUALIZAÇÃO É SÓ IMPLEMENTAR 1 NO STATUS
        $.getJSON('json/json_atualize_me.asp',function(data){
                if( data[0].status == true ){
                        $.post('acao/json_atualize_me2.asp',{ status : 0 },function(data2){
                                window.location.reload(true);
                        });
                }else{  /* se quiser coloque algo aqui */ }
        });
});
```

Conteúdo da página json_atualize_me.asp:

```
<!--#include file="json_query.asp"--> ( veja mais informações sobre este arquivo )
<%
sql = "select status from "&bd_&".atualize_me;"
QueryToJSON(conn,sql).Flush
%>
```

Conteúdo da página json_atualize_me2.asp:

```
<!--#include file="../../bd/conn.asp"-->
<%
status = Replace(Trim(Request("status")),"'","")
sql = "update "&bd_&".atualize_me set status="&status&" where id=1;"
conn.execute(sql)
%>
```

No HTML inclua a chamada para o script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/arquivo.js"></script>
```

Digamos que o Site ou Sistema já está em Produção/Online e são muitos clientes acessando, basta atualizar o campo status = 1 na tabela atualize_me, pronto o próprio arquivo irá efetuar essa requisição 1 vez e se necessário zera o cache do navegador.
Obs: Testado no Chrome e Firefox = ok