# JavaScript para de funcionar e só volta com cache vazio?

Tags: javascript

Ultimamente eu tenho tido muita raiva de JavaScript, o motivo é que eu escrevo meus códigos e funções em JavaScript e elas aparentemente não funcionam. Aí eu preciso abrir o navegador em aba anônima, aí elas funcionam. As vezes preciso limpar todo o cachê do navegador para as alterações que fiz no código voltar a funcionar. Tem vezes que mesmo limpando o cachê do navegador e abrindo no modo anônimo o código não funciona, aí para vê-lo funcionar eu preciso mandar ele no meu servidor em um domínio de testes para conseguir testá-lo.

Por que isso acontece? Porque toda vez que altero um código em JavaScript ele nunca funciona de primeira e me obriga a ter que ficar fazendo toda essa gambiarra pra fazer o código funcionar?

Quando finalmente eu consigo rodar um código em JavaScript após limpar o cache ou utilizar em aba anônima, ele permanece funcionando um bom tempo, mas de acordo com o que eu vou dando *refresh* na página (para testar alterações) ele volta a parar de funcionar. Isso me preocupa, pois e se isso acontecer com o usuário que acessa meu site e as funções pararem de funcionar de acordo com o número de acessos que ele faz no site?

Eu declaro todos os scripts no final do código antes de fechar `body`.

Comment: A questão do cache não é gambiarra, é o comportamento natural do navegador que te ajudará muito em ambiente de produção. Para contorná-lo, você pode ler [Forçar atualização de arquivo javascript sem desativar cache](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68382). Agora, para saber do porquê ele para de funcionar depois de alguns acessos, você precisará postar os códigos aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O cache do navegador é justamente para otimizar uma aplicação web, aproveitando o conteúdo da página para que não seja necessário recarregar alguns recursos toda vez que a página for atualizada. O que eu sugiro para o ambiente de desenvolvimento, seria o uso do navegador **Chrome**. Aperte F12 para abrir a janela de **Inspeção de Código**, clique nos 3 pontinhos que fica no topo da janela e depois clique em **Settings** para abrir as configurações. Marque a opção **Disable cache (while DevTools is open)** como na imagem abaixo:

[image: DevTools]

E sempre que estiver desenvolvendo e testando seu código, deixe aberto a janela de **Inspeção de Código**.

Answer (score -3):

A solução lógica é o cache que feito no primeiro carregamento como você já deve saber. Isso explica o por que uma atualização no código não roda de primeira. Eu aperto umas 5 ou 6 vezes o `F5` para ocorrer a atualização do cache. E assim vejo a minha atualização funcionar.