# Tratar cache com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cache

Tenho uma aplicação com `AngularJs`, nessa aplicação quando faço alguma alteração e em seguida o `deploy` o navegador não reconhece essas alterações. Só funciona quando troco a `URL` dessa aplicação.

Recebi algumas dicas aqui no `SOpt` pra utilizar `querystring` com `Timestamp`, porém gostaria de tentar resolver esse problema utilizando algo próprio do `AngularJS`

Teria alguma maneira de desativar ou tratar o cache para que esse problema não aconteça?

Comment: O angularJS é um framework Javascript, você não vai conseguir resolver o seu problema de cache no client-side, o ideal seria estabelecer o tempo de expiração dos arquivos no servidor.

Comment: E quanto a isso: http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Não funcionaria?

Comment: Seu cache é de template ou dos arquivos.js?

Comment: De template, se eu adiciono um menu e faço `deploy` esse menu não aparece, ao menos que eu limpe o cache.

Answer (score 1):

O Browser não reconhece, porque justamente o script `AngularJs.js` já existe no cache do navegador. Para que qualquer script seja recarregado, por que você não tenta utilizar  `window.location.reload(true)`. Caso deseje outra alternativa, te aconselharia fazer uma função `rand()` no momento em que você carrega o `AngularJs.js` e adicionar como "parâmetro" GET, dessa forma sempre o caminho vai ficar sendo "alterado" e o browser vai entender que é pra baixar esse novo script.

Exemplo com `PHP`:

```
<script src=\"AngularJs.js?r=<?php echo rand(0,10); ?>" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
```