# Edições na página HTML não aparecem no site

Tags: html

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento de site, um amigo me solicitou alterações básicas na *index* (somente mudar um texto), então fiz a mudança e substitui o arquivo na FTP.

O que ocorre é que quando eu digito `www.xxx.com.br` ele simplesmente não está atualizado com as minhas alterações, mas quando digito `www.xxx.com.br/index.html` fica correto.

Então minha pergunta é onde altero esse arquivo que direciona na `www.xxx.com.br`? Há algum outro local para alteração? Tenho acesso somente ao FTP onde contei os arquivos do site, tem algum outro lugar que devo acessar?

Comment: Limpe as "Imagens e arquivos armazenados em cache" do seu navegador ou tente usar o modo anonimo e entre no seu site e verifique se o conteúdo mudou ou ainda da o mesmo problema.

Comment: Limpei a cache de imagens do meu navegador e funcionou mesmo, mais sempre vou precisar fazer isso então ? e as pessoas que já acessaram o site, todas teram que fazer isso ? tem algo para que eu resolva isso ?

Comment: Ué, Sabino = Luiz ?

Comment: Sim, eu que pensei que meu email não estava cadastrado no forum

Comment: Você pode determinar o tempo de cache no navegador do usuário, criando ou editando o arquivo htaccess no seu site. Veja: https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Habilitar_cache_via_htaccess

Comment: @Sabino ou Luiz, segue https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20763/57801

Comment: resolvido, vlw pessoal

Answer (score 0):

Existe o cache do navegador e do servidor. Quando subimos um arquivo e ao remover o cache do navegador e o projeto ainda está com o estado anterior estamos falando de cache do servidor. Não deveria demorar muito, entretanto esse tipo de configuração de cache pelo servidor pode variar de acordo com a hospedagem. E sim, isso é algo comum, eventualmente o cache acaba.