# Problemas com Cookies e Cache na programação

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com uma dúvida que pode parecer muito amadora e sem contexto para se esclarecer no stackoverflow. Também não sei se encontrarei uma resposta aqui.

Porém eu tenho um problema (que não sei se é algo que acontece só comigo) em que sempre que estou programando e faço alterações no código, chega um determinado momento em que as mudanças dos códigos não surtem mais efeito (visualmente). Então eu tenho que rodar um CCLEANER ou qualquer outro programa similar para que as mudanças possam surtir efeito. (Isso quando estou programando no localhost).

Acontece também de (na empresa onde eu faço estágio) eu realizar uma alteração no sistema e fazer upload dos arquivos para a hospedagem, então o Sistema Web não apresenta mudanças naquele exato momento (mesmo que eu atualize a página). O sistema só apresenta mudanças quando eu rodo o CCLEANER. Basicamente eu utilizo para programar PHP e JavaScript, além de HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, jQuery e mais algumas bibliotecas.

**Minha pergunta é:**

- O que o CCLEANER faz (limpa) no navegador, além de cache e cookies, para realizar isso que citei acima ?
- Existem alguma função PHP ou JavaScript (jQuery) que faça o papel do CCLEANER e eu não precise rodá-lo para que o Sistema mostre as atualizações logo após eu fazer o upload dos arquivos ?

Obrigado!

Comment: acredito que um `ctrl` + `F5` possa resolver tbm, pois atualiza e limpa o cache ao mesmo tempo

Comment: @PHPatrick , isso que relatei costuma acontecer com você ?

Comment: A única coisa que o CCleaner faz que resolve o problema é excluir justamente os arquivos em cache para limpar espaço do computador. Cache deveria ser seu amigo, só depende de você. [O que faz a invalidação de cache ser uma solução difícil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356320/5878) Implementar qualquer coisa que limpe o cache tal como o CCleaner seria uma medida paliativa e não definitiva. Ao invés de procurar por isso, procure como gerenciar o cache ao seu favor.

Comment: Relacionada [Limpar cache de navegadores com javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20762/5878)