# Como obter nome do usuário/visitante e escrevê-lo na tela?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Vocês sabem como perguntar o nome do usuário e usar?
Eu Estou montando um site que também é uma loja virtual.
Quero que a loja seja bem gentil com quem entrar,
Perguntando nome, tratando bem, dizendo "Pronto, Esse item foi para seu carrinho, Amanda."
Mas eu gostaria de saber, como pergunto o nome da pessoa, e salvo ele em um cookie?
E Como eu posso usar o nome no site inteiro com o cookie?
Eu já procurei, mas só pergunta o nome, e não usa ele. Só dá as boas vindas.
Eu gostaria de usar o código em todo o site, saldando o usuário, falando com ele.
Para isso, creio que seja necessário um cookie.

Obrigado.

Comment: Hugo, creio que o que você precisa é usar sessions ($_SESSIONS em php), e não cookies. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-a-usar-sessoes-no-php/

Comment: Comentário interessante. Mas não é o que eu estou procurando. Obrigado :)

Comment: Ok, boa sorte então =)

Answer (score 2):

Para salvar um nome no cookie:

```
setcookie("nome", "Nome da Pessoa", time()+3600, "/");
```

Para usar o cookie:

```
echo $_COOKIE["nome"];
```

Você pode configurar o tempo para o quanto quiser. No exemplo está para expirar em uma hora (3600 segundos).

Comment: Não sou autor da pergunta e sinto muito em reviver essa pergunta, mas sua resposta serviu de grande ajuda para mim, agradeço muuito

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback @VictorGomes, é sempre bom poder ajudar..

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo qual problema você esta tendo.

```js
window.String.prototype.novaString=function(de,ate){
    try{
        return this.split(de)[1].split(ate)[0];
    }catch(e){}
    return;
}
if(!document.cookie.novaString("nome=",";")){
    document.cookie="nome="+prompt("Digite seu nome:","");
}
document.getElementById("carrinho").onclick=function(e){
    alert("Pronto, Esse item foi para seu carrinho, "+document.cookie.novaString("nome=",";")+".");
}
```

```html
<input value="Adicionar ao carrinho" type="button" id="carrinho">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdurzz3s/

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa com Javascript é utilizar [**`window.sessionStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) ou [**`window.localStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), a explicação para decidir quando utilizar uma ou outra já foi respondida [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19387/4808).

[**<kbd>DEMO no JSFiddle</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/re22/n1p1mrty/)

```
if(window.sessionStorage){

    if(!sessionStorage.getItem("nome")){
        // Não há um valor definido ainda, então é exibido o prompt para ser inserido o nome.
        // Se o usuário não preenchê-lo, será utilizado o valor "usuário" para referir-se a ele.
        var nome = prompt("Qual o seu nome?") || "usuário";
        sessionStorage.setItem("nome", nome);
    }

    // Há um valor definido, então a mensagem é exibida.
    alert("Olá " + sessionStorage.getItem("nome") + "!");
}
```

<sub>**PS:** Para o que está pretendendo fazer, a solução e o *link* apontado [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64433/como-obter-nome-do-usu%c3%a1rio-visitante-e-escrev%c3%aa-lo-na-tela#comment131926_64433) pelo rafaels88 é a melhor escolha.</sub>