# Qual a diferença entre Local Storage, Session Storage e Cookie?

Tags: html, html5, cookies, localstorage

Qual a diferença entre `Local Storage`, `Session Storage` e `Cookie`? Qual a finalidade de cada um deles e o que os diferencia?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo é, eu vi essa... só faltou a parte dos `Cookies`

Comment: veja tb http://saindodacaixinha.com.br/2015/11/cookies-localstorage-sessionstorage/

Comment: Juntando com essa acho que é dup https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115190/101