# sessionStorage com tempo de expiração

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz um pequeno *script* aqui, mas não estou conseguindo fazer uma personalização nele.

Preciso definir um tempo de expiração para `sessionStorage`. Segue abaixo o *script*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (sessionStorage){
    if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem('visualizado')){
    document.getElementById('inauguracao').style.display='block';
    sessionStorage.setItem( 'visualizado', 'verdadeiro' );}}
</script>
```

Ele vai exibir uma imagem para o usuário, e vai ocultar se já foi visualizado, só que preciso que ela volte a ser exibida após um período de por ex: 30 minutos.

É possível implementar nesse script?

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de trabalhar com `visualizado`, você vai precisar trabalhar com `hora`.

Assim você pode fazer a programação para validar de quanto em quanto tempo deve ser exibido.

Removi a sua variável "**visualizado**" e adicionei a variável "**tempoExibido**". Outra dica é, não precisa ter o getItem e o setItem para o sessionStorage. Você pode trabalhar com ele como um objeto javascript. No exemplo abaixo, coloquei para a cada 10 segudos verificar se precisa exibir novamente e, configurei para que seja exibido a cada 1 minuto. No seu caso, altere a variável "minutos" para 30.

O código está comentado, então acredito que esteja fácil seu compreendimento.

```
setInterval(function(){

    if (sessionStorage)
    {
        console.log('Iniciando...');

        // 30 Minutos
        var minutos = 1;

        // Calcula em milisegundos o tempo acima setado
        var mostrarEntre = 60 * minutos * 1000;

        // Resgata o valor da última exibição
        var exibidoUltimaVez = sessionStorage.tempoExibido * 1;
        var agora = + new Date();

        // Verifica se nunca exibiu ou, se neste momento já deve ser exibido de novo
        if(exibidoUltimaVez === null || agora >= (exibidoUltimaVez+mostrarEntre))
        {
            console.log("Exibindo em: %s", new Date())

            // Atualize para ter o valor da última vez exibida
            sessionStorage.tempoExibido = agora;

            document.getElementById('inauguracao').style.display='block';
        }
    }
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma leitura inicial que é interessante:

[Diferenças entre localStorage Vs sessionStorage?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19384/5878)

Se deseja persistir o valor entre sessões da página, você deverá utilizar `localStorage`. Pelo que li, esses valores não possuem, por padrão, como definir o tempo de vida, então, para o seu caso, como o valor no registro não é importante, você pode armazenar o valor do *timestamp* atual e sempre verificar a quantidade de tempo que se passou desde sua criação até o atual em uma nova sessão. Esta verificação fica algo parecido com isso:

```
// Verifica se existe o registro local:
if (localStorage.getItem("visualizado")) {

  // Recupera o timestamp atual:
  let now = Date.now();

  // Calcula a diferença entre o atual e o registro:
  let diff = now - localStorage.getItem("visualizado");

  // Define o tempo (ms) que durará o registro:
  let delay = 1*60*1000;

  // Se a diferença for maior que o tempo de duração:
  if (diff >= delay) {

    // Remove o registro:
    localStorage.removeItem("visualizado");

  } else {

    // Senão, exibe o tempo de vida restante (opcional):
    console.log("Você já visualizou a imagem no último minuto. Volte em " + (delay - diff)/1000 + "s.");

  }
}
```

Já a lógica para exibir a imagem fica basicamente a mesma, apenas alterando o valor persistido no registro:

```
// Se não existir o registro:
if (!localStorage.getItem("visualizado")) {

  // Exibe a imagem:
  console.log("Imagem foi exibida.");

  // Armazena o timestamp atual no registro:
  localStorage.setItem("visualizado", Date.now());

}
```

> Veja funcionando no [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tuhikucoqo/1/edit?js,console), para um tempo de 1 minuto.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
(function () {
 var minuto = 0;
 setInterval(function () {
   if (minuto == 30) {
      aviso();
     minuto = 0;
   } else {
     minuto += 10;
   }
 }, 600000);//10 minutos

 var aviso = function () {
   if (sessionStorage.getItem('visualizado') == '0') {
       document.getElementById('inauguracao').style.display = 'none';
       sessionStorage.setItem( 'visualizado', 1);
   } else {
     document.getElementById('inauguracao').style.display = 'block';
     sessionStorage.setItem( 'visualizado', 0);
   }
 }
})();
</script>

<div id="inauguracao" style="background-color: red;display: none">Teste</div>
```

Assim funciona.