# Qual a diferença de armazenamento entre sessão, cookies e localstorage?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, session, cookies

Onde é o local de armazenamento de cada um deles? o `local storage` eu ouvi dizer que é do `html5` e é melhor que `session` e `cookie`, qual a diferença entre eles?

Comment: Lembra qual é a fonte de onde "ouviu que localStorage é melhor que os outros"?

Comment: e [Diferenças entre localstorage vs sessionstorage](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-localStorage-Vs-sessionStorage)

Comment: Eu ouvi em um curso que estou fazendo, por isso fiquei curioso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim. O local storage e Session Storage são dois métodos que fazem parte da atualização do DOM do HTML5. Chamamos estes métodos de Web Storage. 
O local storage e o session storage como todos os elementos do DOM podem ser manipulados com Javascript e/ou Json.
Para ser bem objetivo vou explicar assim:

Local Storage: com ele você pode armazenar dados privadamente no navegador. Os dados ficarão persistidos até que o usuário acione o método para destruir o objeto.
Exemplos de uso:

- Formulários onde se deseja armazenar os dados até que o usuário termine o preenchimento e envie. Isso evita que no caso de uma pane de energia ou em um fechamento acidental do navegador o usuário tenha de digitar tudo de novo.

Já no caso do session storage, o objetivo é o mesmo. a única diferença é que, os dados serão armazenados de forma diferente para cada aba do navegador e, se no caso o usuário fechar a aba os dados daquela aba serão apagados automaticamente.
Exemplos de uso:

- Sites de compras de passagens, seja de ônibus ou de passagem aérea.

Cookies: São **arquivos** que servem para os mesmos objetivos de armazenar dados do usuários para serem usados na aplicação/site. A diferença é que os cookies são armazenados no computador cliente e têm desempenho inferior comparado ao web storage.
Exemplo de uso:

- Armazenamento de pesquisas, armazenamento de páginas acessadas, etc.

Sessão: Protocolo/método utilizado para criar a linha de comunicação de forma autenticada entre seu usuário e o programa/aplicativo a ser utilizado. Ou seja, na sessão os dados devem ser criptografados na transmissão. 
Exemplo de uso:

- Login de usuário no facebook, no stackoverflow, autenticação de usuários em proxy corporativo, dentre outros.

Espero ter ajudado. 
Grande abraço. \o/