# Como armazenar variáveis dentro da cache do browser? (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um formulário e quero armazenar os dados que o cliente digitar na cache do browser, caso a aba for fechada o cliente não precise digitar tudo novamente.

Qual o melhor meio para suprir essa necessidade?

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferenças entre localStorage Vs sessionStorage?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%c3%a7as-entre-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage)

Comment: Sim, no comentario de baixo ele me deu o exemplo de localStorage, mas como eles funcionam e qual o melhor?

Comment: Dê uma olhada pergunta que adicionei, acredito que resposta sua pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar *WebStorage* de um Objeto, como por exemplo um *localStorage* dos campos:

imagine que você tem dois campos de *input* um com `ID = name` e outro `ID = lastname`
você pode fazer *localstorage* desses campos desse modo:

```
var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
localStorage.setItem("lastname", lastname);
localStorage.setItem("name", name);
```

onde a primeira parte dentro dos parenteses representa o nome do "atributo" de localStorage, podendo ser referenciado por  `localStorage.lastname` / `localStorage.name`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, cara, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

Para além da **localStorage**, também existe a **sessionStorage** (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), que acaba por ser mais segura, visto que é baseada na sessão, e complementado com um sistema de autenticação, pode ser controlado pelo tempo