# Guardar dados do input sem submit

Tags: php, javascript

O meu problema é que estou fazendo um cadastro de empresas, neste cadastro tenho o campo Ramo de atividades que dispõe de um combo com os ramos de atividades cadastrados na base de dados, o problema é quando temos que incluir um novo ramo de atividades. Nesse caso, tenho um botão que abre uma nova janela para realizar este cadastro, depois do cadastro ter sido concluído ele dá um reload (refresh) na página do cadastro principal e é neste momento que perco as informações.

Queria saber se é possível manter as informações do `form` de alguma forma após eu cadastrar o ramo de atividade novo, que quando voltasse para a página do cadastro principal voltasse com os valores que estavam preenchidos antes.

Comment: Pode utilizar [`sessionStorage` ou `localStorage`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19384/4808) para isto.

Comment: Consegue me ajudar com um exemplo de como fazer com um dos dois ?

Comment: O ideal é usar Ajax na nova janela e adicionar dinamicamente um novo item no combo sem dar refresh na página.

Comment: @Kevin.F conseguiu utilizar o exemplo que criei para ajuda-lo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, é possível sim.

Fiz um código simples com comentários que irão te ajudar à entender como fazer isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


window.onload = function() {
        //Uso de localStorage
        //var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
        //var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        //var phone = localStorage.getItem("phone");
        var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
        var email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
        var phone = sessionStorage.getItem("phone");
        if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val(name);
        if (email !== null) $('#inputEmail').val(email);
        if (phone !== null) $('#inputPhone').val(phone);

}

function myFunction() {
    //Uso de localStorage
    //window.localStorage.setItem("name", $('#inputName').val());
    //window.localStorage.setItem("email", $('#inputEmail').val());
    //window.localStorage.setItem("phone", $('#inputPhone').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", $('#inputName').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", $('#inputEmail').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("phone", $('#inputPhone').val());
    location.reload(true);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="form-actions">
        <form>
            <table cellpadding = "5" cellspacing ="10">
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td style="width: 100px;">
                        <div>Name:&nbsp;<font color="red">(*)</font></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Nome" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td>
                        <div>Email:&nbsp;<font color="red">(*)</font></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="span3" placeholder="Email" id= "inputEmail" type="email" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="control-group">
                    <td>
                        <div>Phone:&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Telefone">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div align="center">
                            <button id="btnConfirm" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction();">Carregar a página</button>
                            <input type="reset" value="Limpar" id="btnReset" class="btn"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Nota:** Basta copiar esse código colar em um arquivo .html para testar localmente.

Bons estudos e espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ele só armazena localmente se eu clicar no botão refresh ?

Comment: No exemplo que fiz, para facilitar o entendimento adicionei no botão refresh para capturar o evento "onClick" e realizar a gravação dos valores, você pode adapta ao seu projeto.

Comment: Mas a ideia é você entender o que o javascript está fazendo neste exemplo.

Comment: Consegue implementar mais uma coisa ? Por exemplo tem como armazenar os dados até sair da página ? Pois neste exemplo é armazenado mesmo saindo e voltando da página, só preciso que fique salvo ao dar refresh.

Comment: Ao sair da página você quer zerar esses valores, é isso?

Comment: Isso, se tiver como depois o resto eu já consigo adaptar no meu projeto.

Comment: @Kevin.F, fiz uma alteração com o que você quer usando o sessionStorage, há uma pequena diferença entre localStorage e sessionStorage que você pode entender melhor aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage?noredirect=1&lq=1 .

Comment: Testei aqui, sai da página fui para uma outra voltei continuo com os valores carregados nos inputs, zerou só na hora que fechei o navegador.

Comment: @Kevin.F espero ter ajudado! Se vc achar que a resposta de fato responde/soluciona a pergunta, vc tem a opção de aceitá-la: veja aqui (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) como e porque fazê-lo. Claro que vc não é obrigado a aceitar nenhuma resposta (apenas se vc achar que realmente respondeu à pergunta), mas isso serve para indicar a futuros visitantes que a resposta soluciona/responde ao que foi perguntado. E bons estudos !

Comment: Caso queira me ajudar e manter incentivado à ajudar a comunidade stackOverFlow poderia adicionar essa resposta como útil, além disso, mais informações sobre aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6139/votar-em-uma-boa-pergunta-ou-uma-boa-resposta-%C3%A9-uma-forma-de-incentivo.